# Where are Email Messages Stored?

Tags: mail.app, time-machine

I need to restore my Apple Mail messages and mailboxes from Time Machine.  Where can I find these files on Time Machine?

Answer (score 5):

The Mail.app stores all Messages in your User Directory:

```
~/Library/Mail/
```

Depending on your OS Version there is a Subfolder, f.e. "V3" for 10.11 and "V2" for 10.10., containing Subfolders for each Mailbox.

The Library Folder is usually hidden, but you can access it in the Finder from the Menu "Go to" > "Go to Folder" (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and typing in the Path listed above.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually restore mail messages directly inside Mail. Make the Mail application active, then enter Time Machine via the menulet. Works similar to file recovery in Finder.